# Macro works first time, then fails on second run when converting formulas to values

Tags: vba, excel

I've been running into a pretty frustrating problem with this macro as of late. I'll run the macro, it'll work exactly as expected, but when I reset it (set up button deleting and clearing sheets) and try to run it again with the exact same data I get a run time error '1004': application defined or object defined error. It highlights one of my  values to values, and despite searching for hours I still can't find anything. My sheet isn't protected, and it's incredibly frustrating to be teased with success like this. Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Also worth noting, this is a pretty large range, I had to apply the autofilter and hide a bunch of columns to prevent it from hitting the 65k formula limit. Thanks!

```
Sub AddMDS()
'Uses SUMIF to find MDS and pair

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastRow2 As Long
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Range("I1").Activate
    Selection.AutoFilter
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:DV" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=19, Criteria1:= _
        "Quantity"

    LastRow2 = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    Range("V4:DQ" & LastRow2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS(MDS!C17,MDS!C5,RC5,MDS!C14,R1C)"
    Range("V4:DQ" & LastRow2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).NumberFormat = "#,##0"

End Sub
Sub ConvVals()
'Converts sumifs to values to enhance speed
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastRow2 As Long
    Dim lastrow3 As Long
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:DV" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=19
    LastRow2 = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    Range("V4:CC" & LastRow2).value = Range("V4:CC" & LastRow2).value
    lastrow3 = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    Range("CD4:DT" & lastrow3).value = Range("CD4:DT" & lastrow3).value
    Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False

End Sub
```

Forgot to mention that the value to value works perfectly with the first LastRow, it fails on the second one. my first thought was that it was hitting the range limit of unique characters, which is why I broke up the range, but even then it still doesn't make sense.

Comment: you appear to be using different columns on the lastrow3 value assignment-CD:DZ on the left and CD:DQ on the right

Comment: Noticed that right after I posted this, fixed it, still having the same issue. Thanks though.

Comment: what's the value of Lastrow2 when the code errors?

Comment: I haven't looked into this too much, but it **MIGHT** be the `Selection.AutoFilter` - This command toggles the autofilter, so, once it's on, then the next time you run it, it'll toggle off which might cause a crash at your autofilter command later on....

Comment: Just ran it with a watch, it's reading it as the proper length of the row. and I misspoke, its lastrow3 that it's breaking on.

Comment: @JohnBustos, why would that break the LastRow3 though? I'll give it a go regardless, I'm just trying to learn the why as well.

Comment: @JosieP, There aren't any blanks, but every time it breaks and gives me the error message, I find the cell where values stop being converted, and for some reason it fills it as blank. I know that it's not blank before it converts though. My only thought is that it's hitting the max limit of formulas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I saw this and realized that I never showed my solution, my apologies everyone. I ended up doing a workaround per se, I just copied and pasted the entire sheet by value into a new one. I still have no idea why this one wouldnt work but the pasting into another sheet definitely did. Hope that helps somewhere!